Drag & drop in MAUI doesn't fire
I'm doing some experiments with .NET 8 MAUI and trying to create a simple component to build a sentence. The working code is on GitHub.

What I like to implement is a drag & drop. So, the idea is the user can drag a button (word) and drop in the StackLayout underneath.
On GitHub, I created this branch to show my implementation.
Every button is created by this function
private Button CreateDraggableButton(string word, bool isSelected = false)
{
    var button = new Button
    {
        Text = word,
        FontSize = TextSize,
        FontFamily = FontFamily,
        BackgroundColor = ButtonColor
    };

    var dragGesture = new DragGestureRecognizer();
    dragGesture.DragStarting += (s, e) => OnDragStarting(s, e, word);
    button.GestureRecognizers.Add(dragGesture);

    var dropGesture = new DropGestureRecognizer();
    dropGesture.Drop += (s, e) => OnDrop(s, e, word);
    button.GestureRecognizers.Add(dropGesture);

    var tapGesture = new TapGestureRecognizer();
    if (isSelected)
        tapGesture.Tapped += (s, e) => OnSelectedWordClicked(s, e);
    else
        tapGesture.Tapped += (s, e) => OnAvailableWordClicked(s, e);
    button.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGesture);

    return button;
}

The functions for the drag & drop are
private void OnDragStarting(object sender, DragStartingEventArgs e, string word)
{
    e.Data.Properties.Add("Word", word);
    e.Data.Properties.Add("Source", sender);
}

private void OnDrop(object sender, DropEventArgs e, string word)
{
    if (e.Data.Properties.ContainsKey("Word"))
    {
        var draggedWord = e.Data.Properties["Word"].ToString();
        var sourceButton = e.Data.Properties["Source"] as Button;

        if (selectedWords.Contains(draggedWord))
        {
            selectedWords.Remove(draggedWord);
            var dropIndex = selectedWords.IndexOf(word);
            selectedWords.Insert(dropIndex, draggedWord);
        }
        else
        {
            AvailableWords.Remove(draggedWord);
            selectedWords.Add(draggedWord);
        }

        UpdateWordButtons();
    }
}

I tried a long press as someone suggested in another post but this is not the case; it still doesn't work. Do you know how can I implement and use properly the drag & drop?

A drag gesture is initiated with a long-press followed by a drag . I test your code,it worked fine. Drag doesn't work when the drag is too fast or far from the source of the drag.

@liyu is it working? on what platform have you checked? On Windows is not working nor in Andriod

It works on Android platform, but it doesn't work on Windows. You can try replacing it with a control that supports operations, such as a frame control.
